# How to implement such a cli script using argsparse?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

Recently I have learned `optdoc` to write my cli script, there were an example which is easily implemented using `optdoc` as fellow:

```
Usage:
  naval_fate.py ship new <name>...
  naval_fate.py ship <name> move <x> <y> [--speed=<kn>]
  naval_fate.py ship shoot <x> <y>
  naval_fate.py mine (set|remove) <x> <y> [--moored|--drifting]
  naval_fate.py -h | --help
  naval_fate.py --version
Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  --version     Show version.
  --speed=<kn>  Speed in knots [default: 10].
  --moored      Moored (anchored) mine.
  --drifting    Drifting mine.
```

I alse wanted to implement such a cli script using `argparse`, however, I found it was much difficult than what I thought.

Like

```
naval_fate.py ship new <name>...
naval_fate.py mine (set|remove) <x> <y> [--moored|--drifting]
```

I toke `ship` and `mine` as two groups, my code is:

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Naval Fate.")
    sub_parse = parser.add_subparsers()

    # ship command
    ship_parser = sub_parse.add_parser("ship", help="ship command info.")

    # mine command
    mine_parser = sub_parse.add_parser("mine", help="mine command info.")
```

For `shine new <name>`, I toke `new <name>` as sub command of group `ship`, but how could implement `new <name>` using argparse? I tried used `ship_parser.add_argument("new", action="store", help="give a new name to the ship")`, while the `new` would parsed as a position arguments, which could not have a value:

```
 ✘ ⚙  args_parse  python3 naval_args.py ship new "new_name"
usage: naval_args.py [-h] {ship,mine} ...
naval_args.py: error: unrecognized arguments: new_name
```

System toke `new_name` as a new position arguments, not as the value of `new`.

I also had question with the implement of `naval_fate.py mine (set|remove) <x> <y> [--moored|--drifting]`.

So how could I implement the script using argparse? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(set|remove)` looks like a `positional` with `choices=['set','remove']`.  'x'` and  'y'` are 2 more positionals (type int?).  the rest looks like mutually_exclusive_group.

Comment: I'd be inclined to give `ship` a subparsers, with 'new', 'move' and 'shoot' parsers.  And make it 'move <name> <x> <y> []'.   `optdoc` allows, even encourages, some formats that are awkward in `argparse` (and other POSIX derived parsers).

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks, bro. I thought `docopt` is much flexible than `argparse`,  as you said, I could take `ship` as a subparsers, with `new` parsers, but it could not give ship a `<name>` postion, if given, all command with `ship` would using a <name> position, which was not matched `ship shoot`.  I was not assure  if `argpasre` supports bound, which mean that only `ship new` need a `<name>`, others no need. So I would rather take `<name>` as the value of `new` instead of another new position argument.